What can cause Playwright to duplicate an action?
I'm writing tests for a small MERN stack blogging application as part of an online course I'm following along with. I've written a few Playwright tests for the user log in, and blog creation. However, I'm having issue testing the blog deletion feature as Playwright seems to be duplicating blogs created that will be used for the test. Here is the my Playwright code:
const { test, expect, beforeEach, describe } = require("@playwright/test");
const { loginWith, createBlog } = require("./helper");

describe("Blog app", () => {
    beforeEach(async ({ page, request }) => {
        await request.post("/api/testing/reset");
        await request.post("/api/users", {
            data: {
                name: "Matti Luukkainen",
                username: "mluukkai",
                password: "salainen",
            },
        });

        await page.goto("/");
    });

    test("Login form is shown", async ({ page }) => {
        await expect(page.getByText("log in to application")).toBeVisible();
        await expect(page.getByTestId("username")).toBeVisible();
        await expect(page.getByTestId("password")).toBeVisible();
        await expect(page.getByRole("button")).toBeVisible();
    });

    describe("Login", () => {
        test("succeeds with correct credentials", async ({ page }) => {
            await loginWith(page, "mluukkai", "salainen");
            await expect(page.getByText("Matti Luukkainen logged in")).toBeVisible();
        });

        test("fails with wrong credentials", async ({ page }) => {
            await loginWith(page, "mluukkai", "wrongpassword");

            const notificationDiv = await page.locator(".notification");
            await expect(notificationDiv).toContainText("wrong username or password");
            await expect(notificationDiv).toHaveCSS("border-style", "solid");
            await expect(notificationDiv).toHaveCSS("color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
            await expect(
                page.getByText("Matti Luukkainen logged in")
            ).not.toBeVisible();
        });

        describe("When logged in", () => {
            beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
                await loginWith(page, "mluukkai", "salainen");
            });

            test("A new blog can be created", async ({ page }) => {
                await createBlog(page, {
                    title: "A blog created by playwright",
                    author: "John Doe",
                    url: "https://google.com/",
                });

                const blog = await page.locator(".blog", {
                    hasText: "A blog created by playwright",
                });
                await expect(blog).toBeVisible();
            });

            describe("And a blog exists", () => {
                beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
                    await createBlog(page, {
                        title: "Test blog 1",
                        author: "John Doe",
                        url: "https://yahoo.com",
                    });
                    await createBlog(page, {
                        title: "Test blog 2",
                        author: "Jane Doe",
                        url: "https://bing.com",
                    });
                });

                test("A blog can be liked", async ({ page }) => {
                    const blog = await page.locator(".blog", { hasText: "Test blog 1" });
                    await expect(blog).toBeVisible();

                    await blog.getByRole("button", { name: "view" }).click();
                    await blog.getByRole("button", { name: "like" }).click();
                    await expect(blog).toContainText("likes 1");
                });

                test("A blog can be deleted", async ({ page }) => {
                    const blog = await page.locator(".blog", { hasText: "Test blog 2" });
                    await expect(blog).toBeVisible();

                    await blog.getByRole("button", { name: "view" }).click();
                    await blog.getByRole("button", { name: "remove" }).click();

                    page.once("dialog", (dialog) => {
                        console.log(`Dialog message: ${dialog.message()}`);
                        dialog.dismiss().catch(() => {});
                    });

                    await expect(blog).not.toBeVisible();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

Here are the helper functions for loginWith and createBlog:
exports.loginWith = async (page, username, password) => {
    await page.getByTestId("username").fill(username);
    await page.getByTestId("password").fill(password);
    await page.getByRole("button", { name: "login" }).click();
};

exports.createBlog = async (page, { title, author, url }) => {
    try {
        await page.getByRole("button", { name: "add blog" }).click();
        await page.getByTestId("title").fill(title);
        await page.getByTestId("author").fill(author);
        await page.getByTestId("url").fill(url);
        await page.getByRole("button", { name: "create" }).click();

        await page.locator(".blog", { hasText: title }).waitFor();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in createBlog:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};

All tests, except for the "A blog can be deleted" test, pass. I notice when I check the test database, it shows that two "Test blog 1" posts are created, and two "Test blog 2" posts are created instead of just one of each. This is also reflected on the app when viewed in the browser.
Browser image:

MongoDB image:

What should have happened is that the two test blogs are created, and then test blog 2 is deleted, leaving on test blog 1 as the remaining post both on the page and in the database.
I also noticed that if I were to remove the blog delete test, the "a new blog can be created" test will timeout. Logging something like this in the console:
@
blog_app.spec.js:62
Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded while running "beforeEach" hook.
@
helper.js:15
Error: locator.waitFor: Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.
Call log:
  - waiting for locator('.blog').filter({ hasText: 'Test blog 1' }) to be visible

I also noticed that if I were to remove the delete blog test completely, and modify the "a blog can be liked test" to the following
test("A blog can be liked", async ({ page }) => {
  await expect(
    page.locator(".blog", { hasText: "Test blog 1" })
  .toBeVisible();
});

the timeout issue goes away, both test blog 1 and 2 are created with no duplication problem, and all other tests pass. I'm not sure what causes this, any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is my App.js code:
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import Blog from './components/Blog'
import Notification from './components/Notification'
import blogService from './services/blogs'
import loginService from './services/login'
import BlogForm from './components/BlogForm'
import Togglable from './components/Togglable'

const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState({
    message: null,
    type: null,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogAppUser')

    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON) // Fixing JSON.parse here
      blogService.setToken(user.token)

      // verifying token validity by attempting to retrieve blogs
      blogService
        .getAll()
        .then((blogs) => {
          setUser(user)
          setBlogs(blogs)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Invalid or expired token', error)
          handleLogout()
        })
    }
  }, [])

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    try {
      const user = await loginService.login({ username, password })

      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogAppUser', JSON.stringify(user))
      blogService.setToken(user.token)

      setUser(user)
      setUsername('')
      setPassword('')

      await blogService.getAll().then((blogs) => setBlogs(blogs))
      setNotification({ message: null, type: null })
    } catch (exception) {
      setNotification({ message: 'wrong username or password', type: 'error' })
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNotification({ message: null, type: null })
      }, 5000)
    }
  }

  const blogFormRef = useRef()

  const addBlog = async (blogObject) => {
    try {
      blogFormRef.current.toggleVisibility()

      const blogToCreate = {
        ...blogObject,
        user: { username: user.username, name: user.name, id: user.id }, // Add user details here
      }

      const returnedBlog = await blogService.create(blogToCreate)

      setBlogs(blogs.concat(returnedBlog))
      setNotification({
        message: `A new blog "${returnedBlog.title}" by ${returnedBlog.author} added`,
        type: 'success',
      })

      setTimeout(() => {
        setNotification({ message: null, type: null })
      }, 5000)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating blog:', error)
      setNotification({
        message: 'Error creating blog',
        type: 'error',
      })
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNotification({ message: null, type: null })
      }, 5000)
    }
  }

  const handleLike = async (event, id) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const blog = blogs.find((b) => b.id === id)
    const updatedBlog = { ...blog, likes: blog.likes + 1 }
    await blogService.update(id, updatedBlog).then((returnedBlog) => {
      setBlogs(blogs.map((blog) => (blog.id !== id ? blog : returnedBlog)))
    })
  }

  const handleDelete = async (event, id) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const blog = blogs.find((b) => b.id === id)
    const accept = window.confirm(
      `Remove blog ${blog.title} by ${blog.author}?`
    )

    if (accept) {
      await blogService.remove(id).then(() => {
        setBlogs(blogs.filter((blog) => blog.id !== id))
        setNotification({
          message: `Blog '${blog.title} by ${blog.author}' has been removed from the server`,
          type: 'warning',
        })
        setTimeout(() => {
          setNotification({ message: null, type: null })
        }, 5000)
      })
    } else {
      setNotification({
        message: `Blog ${blog.title} has already been removed from the server`,
        type: 'warning',
      })
      setTimeout(() => {
        setNotification({ message: null, type: null })
      }, 5000)
    }
  }

  const handleLogout = () => {
    console.log('logged out')
    window.localStorage.removeItem('loggedBlogAppUser')
    blogService.setToken(null)
    setUser(null)
    setBlogs([]) // Clear blogs on logout
  }

  const loginView = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>log in to application</h2>

      <Notification
        message={notification.message}
        type={notification.type}
      />

      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <div>
                    username
          <input
            data-testid="username"
            type="text"
            value={username}
            name="Username"
            onChange={({ target }) => setUsername(target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
                    password
          <input
            data-testid="password"
            type="password"
            value={password}
            name="Password"
            onChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )

  const blogView = () => (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>blogs</h2>

        <Notification
          message={notification.message}
          type={notification.type}
        />
        <p>
          {user.name} logged in <button onClick={handleLogout}>logout</button>
        </p>
      </div>

      <Togglable
        buttonLabel={'add blog'}
        ref={blogFormRef}
      >
        <BlogForm createBlog={addBlog} />
      </Togglable>

      {blogs
        .sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes)
        .map((blog) => (
          <Blog
            key={blog.id}
            blog={blog}
            handleLike={handleLike}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  )

  return <div>{user === null ? loginView() : blogView()}</div>
}

export default App

blog service
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = '/api/blogs'

let token = null

const setToken = (newToken) => {
  token = `Bearer ${newToken}`
}

const getAll = async () => {
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  }
  const response = await axios.get(baseUrl, config)
  return response.data
}

const create = async (newObject) => {
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  }
  const response = await axios.post(baseUrl, newObject, config)
  return response.data
}

const update = async (id, blogObject) => {
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  }
  const response = await axios.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, blogObject, config)
  return response.data
}

const remove = async (id) => {
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  }
  const response = await axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, config)
  return response.data
}

export default { setToken, getAll, create, update, remove }

I don't think the issue is in the backend, as manually creating posts, or even using Postman to test post addition and removal works just fine. However, through Playwright tests, this issue seems to occur.

Worth considering: Avoid nesting when you're testing. Are you sure this isn't a bug in the React code, maybe something to do with strict mode? page.once("dialog", (dialog) => { looks like a race condition, you'll need to begin listening before you trigger the dialog. Can you share a [mcve] of the page that causes the problem and minimal Playwright code necessary to reproduce the issue? The idea is to try to remove distractions until you isolate the problem. Thanks.

Please read this: "As a result, the following snippet will never resolve: WRONG! [code with click before dialog like yours]"

I added the App and blog service code @ggorlen

When I check the newtwork tab of Playwright when in UI mode, it shows that only two post requests are made with the correct blog details. So I think it's a rendering issue in the frontend, I'll double check again.

Thanks for the update. If it's a rendering issue on the front end, you should be able to reproduce it with user actions.
